# Clunking Noise from Rear, Right Tire when hitting bumps

Tags: ford, noise, suspension, struts, taurus

I have a 2003 Ford Taurus SE with ~95000 miles. It has been a very cold and harsh winter in New England. Recently, I have been hearing a clunking noise in the rear, right tire region when hitting bumps, both small and large. I can pretty much hear the noise even on slight bumps but it is most noticeable with bigger bumps. I haven't been able to check this yet because I do not have a garage and the temperatures here have been below 10 degrees consistently. What do you guys think?

Comment: Possible swaybar link issue or a broken strut spring?

Comment: Could also be a worn out/broken strut/shock mount. Look at any of the places where the rear suspension comes together for worn out parts or cracked rubber.

Answer (score 2):

This could be one of several things:

- Swaybar links broken or missing
- Worn out strut/shock mount (on either end)
- Worn out suspension parts ... anywhere the suspension has a bushing which meets the car itself

Without being there in person, it's hard to tell beyond that what it might be. I mean, it could also be a loose spare in the trunk area.

Answer (score 1):

You have just described the sounds of a failing shock absorber / strut.  The top of your strut / absorber does not force out fast enough and creates the bouncing ball effect.